# Best way to append additional result columns from joined table several rows in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

Suppose an example that is similar to Stackoverflow. You have a content item (question or answer) and you fetch data about each individual content item. Each one is being represented by data like:

- title
- details
- score
- etc.

And then you'd also like to attach additional columns representing user interaction related to individual content item:

- user voted up
- user voted down
- user commented
- user flagged item for spam
- etc.

This would give me the possibility to indicate which content items user interacted with and what that interaction was. Now content items are stored in the `Posts` table while actions (voting, commenting) are being recorded in separate table `PostActions` with columns:

- `PostId`
- `UserId`
- `ActionType` (vote up/down, comment, spam, close etc.)
- `CreationDate`

So for each item there are several rows in this table related to each item. User may have done several actions on the same item.

I could execute i.e.

```
select p.*, pa.ActionType
from Posts p
    left join PostActions pa
    on ((pa.PostId = p.PostId) and (pa.UserId = @UserId))
```

but this would result in several rows related to the same content item. To get them all in one result row I could:

1. Use `left join PostActions` several times, for each action individually

   ```
   select
       p.*,
       iif(paUp.CreationDate is null, 0, 1) as VotedUp,
       iif(paDown.CreationDate isnull, 0, 1) as VotedDown,
       ...
   from Posts p
       left join PostActions paUp
       on ((paUp.PostId = p.PostId) and (paUp.UserId = @UserId) and (paUp.ActionId = @UpVoteType))
       left join PostActions paDown
       on ((paUp.PostId = p.PostId) and (paUp.UserId = @UserId) and (paUp.ActionId = @DownVoteType))
       ...
   ```

   but this would end up with many `left join` to the same table
2. I could `left join PostActions` and concatenate all existing actions using `stuff` function and then parse that on the mid tier
3. Whatever else - i.e. grouping by `PostActions.PostId` and `PostActions.UserId` and then getting that info from the group (if at all possible to filter the same group with several different conditions).
4. Using `pivot` or `apply` to get my data

### Question

The main question is which method (one of the above or any other) would be **best in terms of performance**? What would you suggest?

Comment: If I understand you correct, I think CASE functionality will bring you a long way, but you maybe also should look into isolating functionality and do a few more queries than trying to get one to do it all.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen My last resort would be getting multi-result but that would require significant changes on my DAL. I'm hoping to get it done with a single query result.

Comment: These **are** multiple results after all. I'd combine them into a single XML and decode it on client.

Comment: @dean: I might as well, but is that the best way of doing it? Would `pivot` be better?

Comment: `pivot` works best for limited number of known columns in the result. XML is more flexible and IMO easier to maintain.

Comment: @dean: I do have a limited and known columns to append. Always the same ones.

Comment: How would you deal with two actions of the same type for a specific item (eg two comments), would it be two columns, `comment1` and `comment2` or two rows? This is what you were trying to avoid, right?

Comment: @dean: that's not relevant. I just want to know whether user commented or not when talking about comment actions. But not how many times.

Comment: OK, it wasn't clear (to me at least). In any case, I'd try to stay away from `pivot` as a way to send data to client, and use XML for reasons already stated.

Comment: @dean: Any particular reason why? And data is going to DAL where it gets POCO'ed and used afterwards using more complex objects... ie. `UpVoteData { Count: x, Voted: true/false }` etc...

Comment: It's easier to maintain in future if need arises.

Comment: @dean: well that's quite subjective isn't it? :) I mean assuming that having SQL query using `stuff` vs. using `pivot` operator is more maintainable than the other.

Comment: Maintainability is subjective? OK, you've been warned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Final implementation

I experimented a bit and related to my upper possibilities is this outcome:

1. Not entirely possible with just multiple joins. Grouping would have to be implemented as well which makes resulting query too complex and a lot less maintainable
2. Requires upper layer post processing to parse concatenated data. Haven't implemented it because it would require more upper layer code changes which would also be more bound to the data layer than desired.
3. I prepared a CTE that generated content interaction data grouped by content items and users and joining results to original query. Runs fine and works as expected. The tricky part is to *filter* data within each group of records to only count particular interactions (see below).
4. A similar approach to #3 is using `pivot` relational operator and I also implemented that, although prepared pivoted data **also needs to be grouped** beforehand to get one record per item.

Between #3 and #4 I decided to go with #3 as it had a better execution plan.

### Filtering within record group solution

As stated in #3 (final implementation) to make my query perform as it should I had to only group once and then filter data within each group of records to get info about individual content interactions.

As I only needed an indication whether a particular user interacted on a content item all these return boolean (SQL `bit` type). The best part is to use a function within `count` aggregation so that only particular records within group are used.

```
with Interactions (Id, UpVoted, DownVoted)
as (
    select
        p.Id,
        cast(count(iif(pa.ActionTypeId = @UpVoteType, 1, null)) as bit),
        cast(count(iif(pa.ActionTypeId = @DownVoteType, 1, null)) as bit)
    from PostActions pa
        join Posts p
        on (p.Id = pa.PostId)
    where pa.UserId = @UserId
    group by p.Id
)
select
    ...
    isnull(i.UpVoted, 0) as UpVoted,
    isnull(i.DownVoted, 0) as DownVoted
from Posts p
    ...
    left join Interactions i
    on (p.Id = i.Id)
where ...
order by ...
```

The good thing with `count` is that it only counts **non null** records so I took advantage of this fact to filter out individual specific user interactions within the same group related to content item.

`COUNT` is my new love. :)